# Replace multiple values with a single value across a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to replace a bunch of values with a single value across my entire r data frame. Can anyone help me with this ?

v <- c(-1,-2,-3,-4)
 replacement value - 999

I used mutate_all from dplyr . How I can use it with a vector ?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(funs(gsub("-1.*","999",.)))
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate_all(~ replace(., . %in% v, 999))
```

---

Or with `across`

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., . %in% vv, 999))
```